# How to pass the structure of a dictionary into a function

Tags: python, json, function, dictionary

I am trying to pass a dictionary that was created automatically into a function that defines the scheme of a JSON.

This is my function:

```
def split_line_items(df_transactions):
    for row in df_transactions.itertuples():
            yield {
                "count_0": row.count_0,
                 "count_1": row.count_1,
                 "count_2": row.count_2,
                 "total_count": row.total_count
                
                }
```

and this is my dictionary:

```
d = {'"count_0"': 'row.count_0',
 '"count_1"': 'row.count_1',
 '"count_2"': 'row.count_2',
 '"total_count"': 'row.total_count'}
```

How can I pass the dictionary into the function without having to modify it manually?

**EDIT**: I don't want to use the data contained in the dictionary, I want to use the structure (key/values) from the dictionary to define a JSON. The example in yield {} is how it should look like.

Comment: You can pass any datastructure to function as an argument.

Comment: what is the output of `df_transactions.head().to_dict()`? Do you **need** a generator?

Comment: Though `df_transactions` would be a weird name for a dictionary. Names prefixed with `df_` are conventionally used for pandas dataframes.

Comment: @Chris especially with an `itertuples` method ;)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I am trying to use the structure of the dictionary as a structure for the JSON. In Yield I define the structure of the JSON.

Comment: Why not rewrite your function so that it takes as input the sort of thing that you want to pass to it?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am going to try this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this, however the question is not very clear.

```
# considering this is your tf_transactions 
transactions  = namedtuple('r',['count_0', 'count_1', 'count_2', 'total_count'])
tf_transactions  = [transactions(1,2,3,4), transactions(1,2,3,4)]

for row in tf_transactions:
    yield {k.strip('\"'): getattr(row, v.split('.')[1]) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I am trying to solve. I just want to use the structure of the dictionary to build a JSON (this is what the function does). At the moment I have to copy the dictionary manually into the function split_line_items(). I want to automatize this process.

Comment: But it does use the structure of the defined d to build json. How is different ? Imagin this is inside you function and namedtuple just to give input example, not needed inside function